# Read a string from user and store it

Tags: assembly

Hello i'm really new to assembly and i'm still a little lost of how everything works no matter how many times I read online forums or tutorials it's still fairly fuzzy. So my first task is to read a string from the user and store it in the data segment. I also want to assume the length of the string will be 20 characters or less and that the user will never enter more than 20 characters. How would I go about this? I currently have:

```
mov ah, 0Ah         ; Function 0Ah Buffered input
mov dx, string_buf  ; ds:dx points to string buffer
int 21h
```

I don't think this will work however...

Answer (score 1):

this DOS Software interrupt need an input buffer.

```
            ; Example using Microsoft Macro Asssembler (MASM)

.MODEL small 
.STACK 100h

.DATA
BUFF DB 20
ACTR DB ?
ASCII 20 dup DB ("$")
DB "$" ; We needd to have one "$" for print function.

.CODE
START:
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AH, 0Ah          ; Function 0Ah Buffered input
MOV DX, OFFSET BUFF  ; ds:dx points to string buffer
INT 21h

MOV AH, 9            ; Print to output device
MOV DX, OFFSET ASCII ; ds:dx points to string
INT 21h

MOV AX, 4C00h        ; Return to DOS with ERRORLEVEL=0
INT 21h
END START
```

-

```
Ralf Browns x86/MSDOS Interrupt List(RBIL)
http://www.pobox.com/~ralf
http://www.pobox.com/~ralf/files.html
ftp://ftp.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/ralf/pub/

inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.F
--------D-210A-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 1+ - BUFFERED INPUT
AH = 0Ah
DS:DX -> buffer (see #01344)
Return: buffer filled with user input
Notes:  ^C/^Break are checked, and INT 23 is called if either detected
reads from standard input, which may be redirected under DOS 2+
if the maximum buffer size (see #01344) is set to 00h, this call returns
immediately without reading any input
SeeAlso: AH=0Ch,INT 2F/AX=4810h

Format of DOS input buffer:
Offset  Size    Description (Table 01344)
00h BYTE    maximum character buffer can hold
01h BYTE    (call) number of chars from last input which may be recalled
    (ret) number of characters actually read, excluding CR
02h  N BYTEs    actual characters read, including the final carriage retur
```

Answer (score -2):

I love the Assembly Language and Im so glad you want to learn it. But you seem kind of new to it and I would recomend getting a book. I think a good one is The Art of Assembly and x86 Assembly. Also that is to advanced after just starting a few nights ago and your syntax is not really how assembly works so I promise you will get better after reading one of those books.

Comment: Yeah Im sorry I couldn't answer your question but I wanted to just help you out. @user2961971

Comment: Your code should work, provided that you're in an environment where you can run DOS (probably an emulator, these days - DosBox or others). You'll have to provide a buffer as Dirk and Ralf show. Why do you think it won't work?